# How to give a program access to make file in root directory

Tags: java, chmod, logging, permissions

i am running  a program which uses log4j.The log4j uses rolling file appender.However its not able to create the file.

I guess its because the creation of file need root access.

The program is running in folder /usr/src/hell0/myProgram and the log file needs to be stored in /usr/src/logFiles/myprogram.log.

But its not storing it there instead its putting everything to system out

Answer (score 1):

If opening the application as root doesn't work (**sudo app_name**), then you can change the ownership of that folder like:

```
sudo chown user:user /usr/src/logFiles
sudo chmod +r+w -R /usr/src/logFiles
```

(change user:user with your username)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the folder /usr/src/logFiles writable by the user that the program is running as.

One Example is:

```
[sudo] chmod 755 /usr/src/logFiles
```

Then whenever you execute the program, it will have write permissions in that folder.

The sudo part may be optional, depending on if you already have write permissions in /usr/src/.

Generally though, if you can, it is much less hassle to run the program in a subdirectory of your home directory, and that way your user has read/write permissions.